# Testing Events and Mail in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am struggling to handle test of an event within a class and a mail call. Is there an alternative to what Laravel 5.5+ comes with, `Mail::fake()` and similar, within Laravel 5.2?

Here is an example test class

```
<?php

namespace tests\SampleTest;

use tests\TestCase;
use App\Foo\Bar; 

class BarTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBar() {
        $class = new Bar();
        $class->methodWithEvent();

        // Event is called. Inside event we call Mail
        $this->expectsEvents(App\Events\BarEvent::class);
    }
}
```

Example Bar Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Foo;

use App\Events\BarEvent;
use Event;

class Bar 
{
    public function methodWithEvent() 
    {
        Event::fire(new BarEvent()); 
    }
}
```

Example Event File - a default Event File
Example Listener File - handler method

```
public function handle(BarEvent $event)
{ 
    $emailData = [
       'from' => 'test@hotmail.com', 
       'email' => 'joe.doe@hotmail.com',
       'title' => 'Test'
    ];

    Mail::send('Test Message', ['html' => 'HTML Message'], function ($mail) use ($emailData) {
        $mail->from($emailData['from']);
        $mail->to($emailData['email'])->subject($emailData['title']);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the `Bar` class as well?

Comment: @ka_lin added an example class

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#event-fake) (the part with `Event::fake()`)?

Comment: @ka_lin yes, I have. Laravel 5.2 doesn't have Event::fake()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Email Capture service like [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/) to help test emails. If you configure your PHPUnit to use your MailTrap SMTP details, all test events can be captured by MailTrap.

Alternatively, you can set the mail driver to `log` so that it's not actually send to the email address, but captured in the Laravel log file.

Laravel 5.2 also supports the `pretend` configuration. If you set `MAIL_PRETEND` in your `.env` file to `true`, Laravel doesn't send out any emails.